# ave and unrepresented interaction results (drop=FALSE) - causes errors

Tags: r, interaction

Take this simple vector `x` and two grouping variables, `g1` and `g2`

```
x <- 1:10
g1 <- rep(1:2, each=5)
g2 <- rep(1:3, c(2,3,5))
```

There are a number of groups in an `interaction` of these variables that are not represented in this current data.

```
table(interaction(g1,g2))
#1.1 2.1 1.2 2.2 1.3 2.3 
#  2   0   3   0   0   5
```

This causes rare errors that can essentially be boiled down to something simple like:

```
ave(x, list(g1,g2), FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==0) stop() else length(x) )
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
```

Now, I see no reason why this should be the case, given that the result of `ave` should always just be the same length as `x`, with unrepresented interaction of groups discarded.
This is an easy fix to `ave`, such as:

```
ave2 <- function (x, ..., FUN = mean) 
{
    if (missing(...)) 
        x[] <- FUN(x)
    else {
        # the only real edit is the following line
        g <- interaction(..., drop=TRUE)
        split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN)
    }
    x
}
```

...which then gives the appropriate result.

```
ave2(x, list(g1,g2), FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==0) stop() else length(x) )
#[1] 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5
```

I guess before I go and suggest the following to a bug tracker, am I overlooking something simple as to why `ave` should not have `drop=TRUE` added?

So the question is, is there a circumstance where `ave` ever needs to know about unrepresented interactions?

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem with `ave`, but rather `stop` is not designed to return an item of length 0. Try this instead:

```
 ave(x, list(g1,g2), FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==0) {vector("numeric",0) 
                                                       }else length(x) )

 [1] 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: `stop()` was just my example to error out when `length==0` - the actual code I had that flopped was `ave(x, list(g1,g2), FUN=function(x) filter(x, 0:1, sides=1)  )` . I guess I could do a check and return a `numeric(0)` as you suggest, but that seems like something that shouldn't even come into play in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `drop` argument to `ave` too:

```
ave(x,list(g1,g2),drop=TRUE, FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==0) stop() else length(x) )
#[1] 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Oh crud, I should have thought of that. Still, I'm perplexed as to why it is necessary.