# Error when using ave for custom function in r

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

I am using the ave() function to find the partial autocorrelation (pacf) for each individual subject in my data.

```
# return pacf coefficient
pacf1 = function(x) { 
  return(pacf(x, lag.max = 1, na.action=na.pass)$acf[1])
}

ave(df$score, df$id, FUN=pacf1) # get pacf coefficient for each ID

Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations
```

I keep getting the time series error on my original huge dataframe. However, when I did it on a sample "made-up" dataframe, this code works. I am not sure why this is an issue.

Is there another way of getting my desired output without using the ave function?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it would be helpful but can you try with `dplyr`, `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new_col = pacf1(score))`

Comment: I'm going to take a stab in the dark here, try: `ave(df$score, df$id, FUN=pacf1, drop=TRUE)` . I suspect it's the same issue as I asked about a while back here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348329/ave-and-unrepresented-interaction-results-drop-false-causes-errors Your `df$id` variable might be a `factor` which has more `levels(df$id)` than are actually present in `df`

Comment: Wow, thanks to you both for the answers. Both worked perfectly.
@thelatemail, yup i think its one of those issues when you filter your dataframe, some factors get removed, but those factors still remain in the dataframe when you levels(df$id) them

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the comments the issue is because some factor levels were filtered from the dataset resulting in an error while using `ave`. We can verify this using the default `mtcars` dataset

```
df <- mtcars 
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl) #Convert cyl to factor
df <- subset(df, cyl!= 4)   #keep rows where cyl is not equal to 4
ave(df$mpg, df$cyl, FUN=pacf1)
```

> Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

We can resolve this by dropping the unused levels

```
df$cyl <- droplevels(df$cyl)
ave(df$mpg, df$cyl, FUN=pacf1)

#[1] 0.234 0.234 0.234 0.209 0.234 0.209 0.234 0.234 0.209 0.209 0.209 0.209
#    0.209 0.209 0.209 0.209 0.209 0.209 0.209 0.234 0.209

#Or as @thelatemail mentions use 
#ave(df$mpg, df$cyl, FUN=pacf1, drop = TRUE)
```

if we use `dplyr` or `data.table` this issue is handled automatically.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(score = pacf1(mpg))


library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, score := pacf1(mpg), by = cyl]
```